# How to use tensorflow debug under PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, tensorflow, pycharm

I have replaced

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
```

with

```
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
    sess.add_tensor_filter("has_inf_or_nan", tf_debug.has_inf_or_nan)

    with sess:
```

and got the following error during execution:

```
    ...
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  File "/home/dims/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/framework.py", line 446, in run
    is_callable_runner=bool(callable_runner)))
  File "/home/dims/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/local_cli_wrapper.py", line 255, in on_run_start
    self._run_start_response = self._launch_cli()
  File "/home/dims/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/local_cli_wrapper.py", line 429, in _launch_cli
    title_color=self._title_color)
  File "/home/dims/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/cli/curses_ui.py", line 492, in run_ui
    self._screen_launch(enable_mouse_on_start=enable_mouse_on_start)
  File "/home/dims/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/cli/curses_ui.py", line 445, in _screen_launch
```

I am executing under PyCharm.

What does it mean and how to overcome?

Comment: That's part of the stack trace, but what's the actual exception? Either way, the code that runs in __enter__ probably needs to run before anything uses a session, so I'd stick to `with tf.Session() as sess:`, only using `sess` inside that block.

Comment: @Dims I'm facing the exact same problem. If you found the solution, please post it. :)

Comment: @Dims I am having the same problem for debugging. Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: I had this problem with tensorflow gpu but it works fine with tensorflow cpu.
Pycharm: 2018.3
Tensorflow: 1.11